# How to get a list of InputMethods supported by iBus engine?

Tags: python, vim, dbus

I have a simple vim plugin that allows son very basic manipulation of iBus engines and input methods within vim. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031653/how-to-change-ibus-input-method-in-python) for details.

To complete the plugin I need a way to obtain a list of supported InputMethods for the currently set iBus engine. For example the mozc engine has Hiragana, Katakana, Latin, WideLatin and Direct. I would like to be able to get this list using Python but I am unable to find out examples or documentation on how.

Also I need a way to find out what is the current active InputMethod but this also have proved to be a difficult task. Mostly due to lack of documentations or examples.

Any tips on how to accomplish these two tasks would be greatly appreciated.